# How to process output and send \n afterwards in Bash?

Tags: json, bash, certbot-external-auth

I am using the following tool: https://github.com/EnigmaBridge/certbot-external-auth#json-mode

The tool returns a JSON object *and waits for `\n` before it continues*.

What I would like to achieve is this:

1. Grab the first JSON object `JSONOUTPUT1=$(certbot ...)`
2. Process the JSON output
3. Send the `\n` input to the certbot command in `JSONOUPUT1` (see point 1)
4. Collect the next JSON object in `JSONOUTPUT2`

I'm not sure where to start to achieve this, any help is welcome.

Comment: Is there any code that you've written, and you've stumbled upon something?

Comment: I'm cheating with Node right now... will share asap

Answer (score 0):

I am guessing you want an '\n' right after your certbot terminates:

```
JSONOUTPUT1=$(certbot ... && echo)
```

Comment: No, the issue is that half way through the script, a JSON obejct should be read and when proccesed an \n should be send